# Setting vector incorrectly in EIGEN

Tags: c++, eigen

I have written an extremely simple function in Eigen, that should create linearly independent vectors. Instead it consistently creates nullvectors. I expect the solution to be embarassingly simple, but I just don't see it.

Why on earth are the components of my vector mpbv not all equal to cos(0) =1.00 (within the accuracy of my pi value)?

Instead I get:

```
ludi@ludi-M17xR4:~/Desktop/tests$ g++ -O3 -w -o medrealbv.x medrealbv.cc -L/usr/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas && ./medrealbv.x
basisvector =
3.11621e-317
 2.0776e-317
6.95251e-310
ludi@ludi-M17xR4:~/Desktop/tests$
```

So, values very close to zero for each component! My programme comes below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Eigen/Dense>      
#define helix 3
#define pi 3.14159


using namespace Eigen;
typedef Matrix<double, helix, 1> VectorXh;

/*-- DECLARATIONS --*/
int basisvector(int m, VectorXh result);


/*--- MAIN ---*/
int main()
{
VectorXh mpbv;
basisvector(0, mpbv);

  std::cout << "basisvector =\n" << mpbv << std::endl;

return(0);
}

/* --- --- */
int basisvector(int m, VectorXh result)
{
    int k;
    double component;


    for(k=0;k<helix;k++)
    {
        component =cos(m*k*2.0*pi/helix);
        result(k) = component;      

    }



    return(0);
}

/* --- --- */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your function signature to this:

```
int basisvector(int m, VectorXh & result) // note the ampersand
```

What you are doing is passing the `result` by value into the function.  The changes you make inside the function to the `result` argument are lost after the function ends.

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I did that again :(